# A correct way to make relationships between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am building a library database and I am stuck on one particular thing.

I have three tables :`BookCopy`, `BookLoan` and `Members`. It is not clear to me how to make the relationships between them, so a member can borrow a book(or books) and all this to be correctly reflected in my database.

My idea was to have a two many-to-many tables, so I add `BoakLoansMembers` and `BookCopiesBookLoans` . I am not sure if this is correct, and even if it is, I have no idea how to scipt so many tables.

So, now I am wondering what would be the best thing to be done in this case and why?

[image]

Comment: You should add a fields in the `BookLoan` such as `BookCopyId` and `MemberId`. If `dateReturned` is `NULL` that means it's not returned yet, otherwise it's returned.

Comment: dont use varchar for date field, mysql have `date` type, same for `numberPages` should be integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have an m:m relationship between Members and BookCopy and use your BookLoan Table as your cross join table. So you basically just have to add the references from the tables Members and Bookcopy to the Table BookLoan

```
  BookLoan
  ---------------
  idBookLoan 
  dateLoaned
  dateReturned

  idBookCopy  FK -- add these two
  idMember    FK
```

And also consider making idBookCopy, idMember and dateLoaned the primary keys of your BookLoan Table

Comment: I think the field idBookLoan is a bit redundant if you have 3 values (dBookCopy, idMember and dateLoaned) that can only be unique by themselves

Comment: While unlikely, it is possible they would not be unique if `dateLoaned` is a date field (without time)... if the member checked it out, changed their mind and returned it, and then changed their mind again and re-checked it out. Avoiding edge cases like these, and ease of referencing the loan table later, are the typical reasons for using synthetic keys.

Comment: Well you got a point there, but I think its up to the programmer to implement it correctly: eg. a timestamp would be suitable and therefore there should not be any edge cases anymore

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your `BookCopy` is to account for having X copies of book Y, and in that sense "books" are not loaned, "copies" of them are, right?

I think the best course of action is probably to realize the `BookLoan` table should be the many-to-many table. A copy is loaned to a member at a time and then returned. `BookLoad` should have the id's for the copy and the member, and the date loaned (as you have now, though it should be a datetime field NOT a varchar one) & date returned (like the loaned date, it should be a datetime, but should also be nullable to represent unreturned copies). You should also keep the unique (presumably auto-increment) id of the loan as it is very possible a member might check out the same copy multiple times.

I am guessing that perhaps you were originally conceptualizing the "loan" similar to a sales transaction, which could work; but you would want a `loanCopies` table, and wouldn't want the dateReturned on the loan then since different copies could be returned independently.

---

Edit (additional observations):

- `isAvailable` may be redundant if it is only based on whether the copy is checked out *(if you want to withhold the book from circulation it might be appropriate though)*
- ISBN maxes at 13 characters according to wikipedia *(char van be a little more efficient than varchar under some circumstances)*
- you might want to consider a languages table that the copy can reference rather than using a string type field.

---

Edit (re: isAvailable):
If you just need to find the copies not loaned out, a simple query like this is all you need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM BookCopy 
WHERE idBookCopy NOT IN (
  SELECT idBookCopy
  FROM BookLoan
  WHERE dateReturned IS NULL
);
```

The subquery gets the list of copies loaned out, and the `NOT IN` makes sure the copies in the results are not in that list.

If you want to prevent a copy from being loaned out (damaged, vandalized, etc...) an `isAvailable` "flag" could be a simple way to add such functionality; just add `AND isAvailable = 1` to the outer query's `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, as far as I understand ,you are suggesting to do what the other person who answererd suggested, am I right? Instead of having the twom many-to-many tables(as in my initial idea) simply to put a bookCopyFK and a memberFK in my BookLoan table, thus avoiding having two connecting tables?

Comment: Exactly, the loan is a connecting table for the copy and member.

Comment: I don't completely get your point on isAvailable. If I don't have this field how would I know if a certain copy is taken or not? And, yeah, regarding the langugage table - I had that, but decided to make it a field, because the table languages would have been in a  one-to-one with bookCopy

Comment: With the languages suggestion, I was considering you might end up with some sort of "alternate titles" table related to books that might contain the title in different languages. Even without that, you also need to consider you would likely be storing hundreds of copies of the strings "English", "Spanish", "German", etc... instead of integers pointing to them; then you have to make sure your input process reduces the potential for having "English", "ENGLISH", "english", "eng", "engliish", etc.... I'll update the answer itself to demonstrate my point about `isAvailable`.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)